# JQuery next sibling with checkbox

Tags: jquery, dom, siblings

I have code generated by a third party tool that looks like this:

```
<tr id="abc0">
  <td class="ABC" id="abc0_def">
    <input onclick="..." type="checkbox" />
  <td class="BodySpacer">
  <td class="ABC" id"abc0_hij">
    <input onclick="..." type="checkbox" />
<tr id="abc1">
  <td class="ABC" id="abc1_def">
    <input onclick="..." type="checkbox" />
  <td class="BodySpacer">
  <td class="ABC" id"abc1_hij">
    <input onclick="..." type="checkbox" />
```

As you can see, the td tags are not properly closed and I cannot control this.

For the checkbox in the `abcX_def` how can I automatically check the checkbox in `abcX_hij`?

I've tried:

```
var n = $(this).parent().nextAll().has(":checkbox").first().find(":checkbox");
n.attr("checked","checked");
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', $(this).is('checked'))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8pz5e/1/)